# oledb.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine but working for some applications

Tags: c#, oledb

I need to read an excel file to datatable.
I have this code:

```
      public static DataTable LoadExcelFileToDatatable(string Filename, string SheetName = "Sheet1")
  {
      try
      {
          string connectionString = System.String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\";", Filename);
          string query = System.String.Format("SELECT * from [{0}$]", SheetName);
          OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
          DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
          dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
          DataTable dt = dataSet.Tables[0];

          return dt;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {

          throw ex;
      }
  }
```

In the project I am using, calling LoadExcelFileToDatatable() will throw
"oledb.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine"
However if I created a new project, and called the same method, it will work fine!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

uninstall the provider and install it again and in the install form when you need to choose the users choose 'For Everyone' instead of 'Just Me'

Comment: While I second the reinstall it shouldnt make 1 project work and not another.. given the OP stated the same method in both.

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on office version.

your using excel 8.0 in properties. it support for 97-2003 format only.

please refer below link

https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: The provider doesn't seem to care when you give it the wrong version in the extended props. Also extended props are used for the file not the provider itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however the same function is working when called to read the same excel file (2007) but in another application I created for testing!